# LESS mixin for generation media queries

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

I'm trying to create a mixin that automates creation of media queries for predefined screen resolutions and base (template design) width. I've made some workaround and it actually works as acspected, but only for the first call of mixin. Try the code [here](http://lesstester.com). I presume that some variable resets is required here to get it done. Here is the code:

```
// --------------------------------------------------
// VARIABLES
// --------------------------------------------------

// PSD-layout design width 
// for default values
@design-width: 1920;

// Media queries 
// to recalculate values for
@media-queries: 768, 1024, 1366, 1920;


// --------------------------------------------------
// MIXINS
// --------------------------------------------------

// Construct selector
.add-selector(@selector-name, @selector-properties)
{  
    @{selector-name} 
    {
        @selector-properties(); 
    }   
}

// Generate media queries
.generate-media-queries(@selectors)
{  
    @length: length(@media-queries);    

    // First iteration (Mobile First)
    .calculation-loop(@selectors, @iterator: 1) when (@iterator = 1) 
    {               
        @query-width: extract(@media-queries, @iterator);
        @ratio: @query-width / @design-width;     

        @selectors();

        .calculation-loop(@selectors, (@iterator + 1));
    }

    // Continue iterations (Media Queries)
    .calculation-loop(@selectors, @iterator) when (@iterator <= @length) 
    {
        @query-width: extract(@media-queries, @iterator);
        @ratio: @query-width / @design-width;       

        @media(min-width: unit(@query-width, px)) 
        {
            @selectors();       
        }

        .calculation-loop(@selectors, (@iterator + 1));
    }

    .calculation-loop(@selectors);
}


// --------------------------------------------------
// SET SELECTORS
// --------------------------------------------------

// First selector set
@block-1: {

    .add-selector(e(".section-1, .section-1>.inner"), 
    {       
        width   : 50% * @ratio;         
    });

    .add-selector(e(".section-2"), 
    {       
        width   : 34% * @ratio;
    });

};

// Second selector set
@block-2: {

    .add-selector(e(".section-3"), 
    {       
        width   : 81% * @ratio;
        height  : unit(floor(145 * @ratio), px);
    });

};


// --------------------------------------------------
// MIXIN CALLS
// --------------------------------------------------

/* First call
-------------------------------------------------- */
.generate-media-queries(@block-1);

/* Second call
-------------------------------------------------- */
.generate-media-queries(@block-2);
```

Please, any help be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In short see [#2849](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2849).

Comment: @seven-phases-max
Thanks a lot, very helpful issue. Figured out finally. Here is a working example [link](https://codepen.io/mosgaz/pen/VaQYab?editors=0110).

Еще раз, большое спасибо!